# Eclipse code completion for Sencha Touch 2.3 without the official Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, extjs, aptana, code-complete

I wish to use Aptana Studio/Eclipse for writing an app using Sencha Touch 2.3. Is it possible to add code completion to Eclipse somehow without resorting to the official (paid) version of the Sencha Touch Eclipse plugin? Some approaches such as [this](http://tol8.blogspot.co.at/2013/02/sencha-ext-js-support-in-eclipse-tested.html) recommend installing the Spket IDE and then adding a jsb3 file. However Sencha touch 2.3 does not include a jsb3 file. In Sencha cmd 4.0 is is impossible to create a jsb3 file using the command *sencha create jsb*. Any suggestions on how to create a jsb3 file or add code completion another way?